# See-Saw lemma for vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\to S$ be a proper flat morphism of varieties, let $L_1,L_2$ be a line bundle on $X$, suppose $L_1$ and $L_2$ are fiberwise isomorphic, then See-saw lemma claims $L_1\cong L_2\otimes f^*N$ for some $N\in\mathrm{Pic}(S)$.

Suppose $L_1,L_2$ are vector bundles of the same rank, under which conditions(fiberwise) shall we have $L_1\cong L_2\otimes f^*N$ for some line bundle $N\in\mathrm{Pic}(S)$?

Comment: What kind of conditions are you expecting? Take $f:X\to X$, the identity map and two vector bundles of the same rank. Little chance you get your isomorphism.

Comment: @Mohan For example, if $X\to S$ is a family of curves, and over all $s\in S$, the restriction to $L_1|_{X_s}\cong L_2|_{X_s}$ are isomorphism of vector bundle on curves?

Comment: My example above is even more general. For example, take any curve $C$ and $S$ any variety with two vector bundles of the same rank on $S$, consider $f:X=C\times S\to S$ and take the vector bundles pulled back to $X$.

Comment: @Mohan Yes you are right, suppose we have a vector bundle on the family which is fiberwise trivial, then is it necessarily the pullback of a vector bundle from the base?